# What are Inorder Successor and Predecessor in Binary Tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

If anyone could clarify **what exactly are inorder successor and predecessor in binary tree**. I found algorithms how to find inorder successor and predecessor for a node in binary tree. But I'm having trouble clearly understanding what exactly inorder successor and predecessor are.

```
             1
           /   \
          2     3
        /  \  /  \
       4   5  6   7
```

What will be the inorder successor and predecessor of **"4" and "7"**?

Comment: Do you know what "inorder" means? The successor and predecessor are the next respectively previous node in this sequence.

Comment: Successor of 4 is 2. Predecessor of 4 is none. Successor of 7 is none. Predecessor of 7 is 3. [This might help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_(LNR)).

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for your help. I understand now.